# strange behavior when using devise: do not show flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

in the sign_in page, I entered nothing and click submit. the page just refresh and no error message appears.

I have flash[:alert] and flash[:notice] in my view:

```
- if flash[:alert]
    div.alert #{flash[:alert]}
- elsif flash[:notice]
    div.notice #{flash[:notice]}
```

the logger says:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-25 12:38:49 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9a85NKpAj3ZJgKnzStvBA3sxGqrShgbUqbjiJrqQCAM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"登陆"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9a85NKpAj3ZJgKnzStvBA3sxGqrShgbUqbjiJrqQCAM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"登陆"}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.slim (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/one_column (5.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.slim (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/site.html.slim (12.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm confused with

```
"Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms"
```

I think there is something wrong..

but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your view page. Don't use 'flash'. According to the template (generated by scaffold)

```
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>      
  <li><%= msg %></li>     
<% end %>
```

You should change the variables in your view page, and you will see the error message such as "username should not be blank" or "用户名不能为空" in Chinese.

Comment: What is `@post` in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you are correct to use:

```
- if flash[:alert]
    div.alert #{flash[:alert]}
- elsif flash[:notice]
   div.notice #{flash[:notice]}
```

My problem was I had my own `config/locales` defined ( en.yml, it.yml, etc ) but I had not copied the Devise entries over from `config/locales/devise.en.yml`.

As a quick test, I added the following to `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  devise:
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Signed in successfully.'
```

After signing in, `flash[:notice]` started working.